# Преимущества и недостатки компиляторов С/Си++ под разными ОС

Tags: c, компилятор, c++

Понимаю, что могу спровоцировать холивар. Но тем не менее, предлагаю обсудить преимущества и недостатки различных компиляторов С, С++. Платформы - Linux (+ *nix в целом), Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel C++ действительно очень хорош для проведения сложных, больших вычислений, очень хорошо реализована OpenMP. Сам регулярно использую там, где нужна большая производительность. Но при компиляции простых приложений, там, где трудно что-то распараллелить, особенно большого преимущества перед gcc не заметил.

Comment: Вас понял. Но при компиляции емких приложений выигрыш в скорости очевиден? Стоит ли использовать вместо привычного gcc (использую для расчетов преимущественно методом КЭ)? Есть данные бенчмарков?

Comment: Очень даже очевиден. Но не просто емких, а тех, где алгоритм расположен к распараллеливанию. Сам экспериментировал и сравнивал. Особенно помогают разные параметры оптимизации под конкретные процессоры. Правда, на процессорах AMD особого преимущества ждать не стоит, поскольку использует разные примочки именно процессоров от Intel (сам не пробовал, основываюсь на чужих сведениях).

Comment: По поводу AMD и понятно. Оптимизация явно для своих процессоров. Но задачи у меня явно не для массового применения, поэтому использовать комп именно с Intel не проблема. Буду пробовать. Каких трудностей следует ожидать при переносе кода с gcc?

Comment: Совместимость неплохая, хотя и не 100%. Сам никаких трудностей не испытывал. Если не требуются какие-то очень "навороченные" параметры компиляции и т.д.,то проблем возникнуть не должно. 
Но ядро компилировать им нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

GCC не имеет недостатков :-D

Comment: =) все мы (особенно Линуксоиды) знаем и уважаем GCC. Сам пишу сейчас исключительно под GCC (включая отличные от PС архитектуры). Однако. Мне нахваливают семейство компиляторов Intel, хорошо оптимизирующих. Есть ли информация (практическая) на эту тему. Какие еще варианты?

Comment: Вы уверены ?  

Поиграйтесь со сравнением на больше-меньше двух ntohl() без явного приведения к unsigned (а в .h она объявлена unsigned) с флагом оптимизации на x86.

Comment: nobody's perfect:)